# iOS draws rectangles for certain fonts of text when using CGcontextshowtextatpoint

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, cgcontext

x and y are integers.

The following code works fine when I send a custom created context using CGBitmapCreateContext and then use it with common fonts like ArialMT:

```
int theSize = [caption.text length];
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, x, y, [caption.text UTF8String], theSize);
```

But when I use certain fonts, the letters show up as rectangles.  So I tried doing what another stack overflow answer suggested, which is to use CoreText:

```
 // supposedly a solution to glyphs problem
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, .5);
[caption.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withFont:caption.font];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

But that just gives me an error: Sep  7 13:33:31 ... : CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances: invalid context 0x0

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle means the glyph isn't available in that font. Using `-drawAtPoint:withFont:` will use font fallbacks to draw the glyphs using other fonts, but note that this *isn't* Core Text, it's just UIStringDrawing. In any case, this is failing because the `-drawAtPoint:withFont:` call relies on the current UI graphics context stack, but you're using a custom context that isn't on the stack. Either use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext[WithOptions]()` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` to create and destroy your CGContext, or use `UIGraphicsPushContext()` and `UIGraphicsPopContext()` to add your context to the stack and remove it again afterwards.

Alternatively you could actually start using CoreText which uses explicit contexts (just like CoreGraphics), but that's going to be more lines of code.